# To throttle the send port, with no coding introduced

Tags: biztalk, send-port

We are currently dealing with the timeout issue for the web service call.

Goal is to throttle the max concurrent outbound calls on send port level, e.g. when source trigger 1000 messages to a send port, in a perfect scenario, BizTalk to pick up 10 msgs a time, rather send 1000 concurrently.

Since BizTalk is build for throughput, is there any setting to throttle on the send port level (or host instance level but not the entire group) without introduce any orchestration coding.

(ordered delivery is not an option for performance reasons)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Ordered Delivery is too much throttling, you have basically two options:

1. User a Resource Dispenser Patter as described in this article: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23924.biztalk-server-resource-dispenser-send-port-edition.aspx
2. Isolate that Send Port in it's own Host/Instance and reduce the number or worker threads (MaxWorkerThreads in the Settings console) to a number just above the number of concurrent connections you think the target can support.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to look at is the maxconnectionsin the configuration section for BTSNTSvc.exe.config and BTSNTSvc64.exe.config

[Setting SOAP, HTTP, and HTTP-based WCF Adapters Concurrent Connections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee290739(BTS.10).aspx)

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="www.contoso.com" maxconnection="20" />
      <add address="*" maxconnection="10" />
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Note that this is maximum connections per BizTalk host instance